# Retrieve complete Twitter timeline

Tags: php, json, twitter

we are working on a PHP webservice which is intended to retrieve a user's twitter timeline.
Now comes the problem, this is the URL we use: "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/$user.json?count=$num&include_rts=1 where $user is the user (^_^) and count the number of tweets to retrieve but it only shows me the tweets generated by the user or the ones reteeted by him.
I need ALL tweets that appear on his timeline, means the one he tweets and the ones people he is following tweets.
Is there any parametermissing in the URL above or do I have to use another method instead?
Thanks in adavance.

Comment: Given the fact that the person might be following people who have protected timelines, it would be impossible to recreate what a person see on his or her timeline. The best you can do is get every person the user follow's timeline and combine them.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I fear it might not be a very good solution due to the huge amount of people this user might be following...if anybody jnows about some other solution, maybe something related to home_timeline (if that's the case I would appreciate any hints coz' I am unable to make home_timeline work :( ) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I answered a very similar question, it would apply in your case too..

use [Twitter Counter](http://twittercounter.com/pages/api?ref=footer) as Twitter only supplies you with numbered I.D's rather then detailed info about followers.

[Counting a Group of Twitter Users' Followers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302543/counting-a-group-of-twitter-users-followers/7302978#7302978)

> MyAccount > MyFollowersAccount > followers_count
>
> What I would do is this,
>
> run the Twitter API method GET followers/ids
>
> https://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=twitterapi
>
> to get the ID's of the followers of screenname X
>
> and then switch over to Twitter Counter which will give you a more
>   detailed list and information about the followers, followers
>   specifically. Also, this could be a way to split up the two calls so
>   you won't be blocked by a rate limit problem on one end.
>
> http://twittercounter.com/pages/api?ref=footer